# Java spring, hibernate foregin key

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, foreign-key-relationship

New to this type of coding to as I'm trying to access values in one table to showup in another table:

```
Table1: Customer
customer_type

Table2: CustomerType
id   desc
1    poor
2    middle  
3    rich
```

A user will have the seclection for the customer type (dropdown).  I have this piece of code for the class Customer and access the table2 in a class called CustomerType but not sure if this will work. Am I on the right track?

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "Customer", fetch =      FetchType.EAGER)
@Column(name = "customer_type", nullable = false)
public CustomerType getcustomerType() {
    return customerType;
}

public void setcustomerType(CustomerType description) {
    this.customerType= description;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you on right track, you will need to modify your tables a bit to make this all run smooth.

Great example for @OneToOne annotation can be found here:

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-one-to-one-mapping-tutorial-using-annotation/